# Transform nested .map methods with async/await model

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm managing a JSON file like this example:

```
[
    {
        "Item": "Item1",
        "ItemChild": [
            {
                "Category": "Category1",
                "Inputs": [
                    {
                        "InputName": "1",
                        "InputTitle": "Title1",
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                "Category": "Category2",
                "Inputs": [
                    {
                        "InputName": "2",
                        "InputTitle": "Title2",
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm parsing this file, getting all the `Category`, `InputName` and `InputTitle` keys values and appending them in a file using this logic:

```
myParsedJSON.map(({ ItemChild }) => {
    ItemChild.map(({ Category, Inputs }) => {
         fs.appendFileSync(myfile, Category);
         Inputs.map(({ InputName, InputTitle }) => {
             fs.appendFileSync(myfile, InputName + ' - ' + InputTitle);
         });
     });
});
```

I want use an asynchronous version of this logic with async/await model and async operations.
What's the best way to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array functions don't play nice with `async` so convert them to `for of` loops

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises

for (const { ItemChild } of myParsedJSON) {
    for (const { Category, Inputs } of ItemChild) {
        await fsp.appendFile(myfile, Category);
        for (const { InputName, InputTitle } of Inputs) {
            await fsp.appendFile(myfile, `${InputName} - ${InputTitle}`);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! @Matt, this solution is very easy and suitable to my case

Answer (score 1):

You would have to really contort this to use async/await, although you could easily convert it to something that you could *`await` somewhere else*:

```
const text = myParsedJSON.map(({ ItemChild }) => {
    return ItemChild
        .map(({ Category, Inputs }) => {
            return Category + '\n' + Inputs
                .map(({ InputName, InputTitle }) => {
                    return InputName + ' - ' + InputTitle;
                })
                .join('\n');
        })
        .join('\n');
});

const awaitableResult = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.appendFile(myFile, text, (err) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(true);
    });
});
```

You can now `await` the `awaitableResult` in any `async` function:

```
async someFunction() {
    await awaitableResult; // file IO done.
    // do whatever needs to happen next.
}
```

Note that we do all of the data processing before we start writing to the file: writing to disk is s-l-o-w, you want to do it as little as possible. If you really want to stay with the piecemeal approach, use `fs.writeStream`.

Comment: Thanks @Jared Smith, your answer is very clear and usefull for me.